# how to count number of 1/0 bits in char [assembly]

Tags: assembly, x86

This is assembly code.It should count, how many times there's a transformation from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 in a char.

```
void main()
{

unsigned char vet[] = { 0x06 }; //Array di byte (da considerare come
                                //una sequenza di bit)
unsigned short int len = 4;             //Lunghezza (numero di bit)

                                        // Output
unsigned int transizioni01;             //Numero di transizioni 0->1
unsigned int transizioni10;             
  __asm{XOR EAX, EAX
        XOR EBX, EBX
        MOV transizioni10, 0
        MOV transizioni01, 0
TORNO:
        CMP BX, len
        JA FINE
        MOV AL, vet[EBX]
        TEST AL, 1
        JNZ UNO

        INC BX
        MOV AL, vet[EBX]
        TEST AL, 1
        JZ ZEROUNO

UNO:    INC BX
        CMP BX, len
        JA FINE
        MOV AL, vet[EBX]
        TEST AL, 1
        JNZ TORNO

UNOZERO:INC transizioni10
        JMP TORNO
ZEROUNO:INC transizioni01
        JMP TORNO

FINE:}
```

Its not working.Can anyone suggest me any changes?

Comment: To get transitions filtered out (as bits marking the second bit of pair) you can do (x ^ (x>>1)) with top bit copied from itself, then for 2nd+ char it's the lowest bit of previous byte. Then by anding this result with original value you will get 0->1 transitions only, then you can count remaining bits. The 1->0 transitions is the count(result)-count(0->1) ... I'm writing this as raw idea out of head, without really verifying it, so it may be wrong (completely). Also it's not clear, how you want to treat first/last bit of the provided array, and where they connect (low to top, or top to low?)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to understand your code, but the following alternative will work:

```
//Assume EAX = pointer to input array of integer
//Assume EDX = length of array in bytes
//Length must be a multiple of 4.
  push edi               //Save non-volatile registers
  push ebx               //I.e. everything but eax,ecx,edx
  xor edi,edi            //change count = 0
  lea eax,[eax+edx]      //array = end of array
  neg edx                //length = - length
  //we turn the counter around, so the loop is more efficient.
  jz @Done               //if length = 0 -> done
@OuterLoop:
  mov ebx,[eax+edx]      //x = array[end - length] => x = array[begin]
@InnerLoop
  bsf ecx,ebx       //count leading zero's, cl = LSB zero-count
  jz @RemainderIsZero
  inc edi           //If reg is non-zero then at least 1 change.
  shr ebx,cl        //shift out the bits we've counted
  not ebx           //Invert the data, force LSB to be zero
  jmp @InnerLoop    //repeat until data = 0 (until no more changes)
@RemainderIsZero:    
  add edx,4         //see if more data needs to be processed
  jnz @OuterLoop    //remember edx is negative
@Done:
  mov eax,edi       //return the count in eax
  pop ebx           //restore the non-volatile registers.
  pop edi
  //ret             //You can only do RET if the compiler does NOT
                    //use stack frames.
```

Comment: But I have to calculate the number of transitions 1 0 and the transitions 0 1 in separate variables. how can I do?
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the array connects from low bit to top bit, i.e. two bytes `0x0F, 0xF0` will be treated as bits stream `0000 1111 1111 0000`, resulting into one (0->1) change, and (1->0) change. The first/last bit is always "no change" (against the void next to it), so `0xFF, 0xFF` will produce 0/0 transitions, and `0x00, 0x00` will produce 0/0 transitions too.

The idea of the code is to use `(X xor (X>>1))` to extract bitmask of bits, where transition happens ("edges"), then to count these to get count of "all" transitions, and when `and`-ed with original `X` value the bitmask of only "0->1" transitions is received, and again counted. Then at end to get count of "1->0" transitions one has just to subtract "0->1" from "all" counts.

```
    ; TODO preserve registers which need to be preserved by your ABI
    ; ax, ebx, ecx, dx, esi, edi will be modified
    lea    esi,[vet]  ; address of byte array
    mov    ecx,[len]  ; number of bytes in array
    mov    ah,[esi]   ; take most significant bit as entry low bit
    shr    ah,7       ; ah.LSB = [first_byte].MSB (no transition on first bit)
    xor    ebx,ebx    ; counter of ALL transitions
    xor    edi,edi    ; counter of 0->1 transitions
    ; ## calculate bitmaks of all transitions (marked bit is the second one)
detect_transitions_loop:
    mov    al,[esi]   ; ax = current source byte + low bit of previous in ah
    shr    ax,1       ; al = 8 bits of array shifted by 1 to right
    mov    ah,[esi]   ; ah = current source byte
    inc    esi        ; ++source byte address
    xor    al,ah      ; al = bitmask of transitions detected
    jz     no_transition_detected_in_byte
    mov    dh,al      ; dh = copy of all transitions
    ; ## count all transitions
count_all_transitions:
    inc    ebx        ; increment number of all transitions
    ; clear least significant set bit of al (removes one transition)
    mov    dl,al
    dec    al
    and    al,dl
    jnz    count_all_transitions ; until all bits are counted
    ; ## count 0-1 transitions
    and    dh,ah      ; dh = bits of 0->1 transitions detected
    jz     no_transition_detected_in_byte
count_01_transitions:
    inc    edi        ; increment number of 0->1 transitions
    ; clear least significant set bit of dh (removes one transition)
    mov    dl,dh
    dec    dh
    and    dh,dl
    jnz    count_01_transitions ; until all bits are counted
no_transition_detected_in_byte:
    dec    ecx
    jnz    detect_transitions_loop
    ; ## calculate 1->0 transitions count, and store results
    sub    ebx,edi
    mov    [transizioni01],edi
    mov    [transizioni10],ebx
    ; TODO restore any registers which had to be preserved
    ; TODO return
```

The code can be extended to process 32 bits at once (if you pad input array to contain multiplies of 4 input bytes), and (on CPUs where available) instruction `popcnt` can be used to count the number of bits of detected transitions.

EDIT: actually to process the array at 32bits at once it would need to have the bits connected in top->low and reversed way (read them from LSB to MSB, i.e. 0x0F = 1111 0000 stream of bits), then loading `mov eax,[esi]` would conform to this on little-endian machine. So it's not that simple as I thought.

Comment: it's right but there's a problem, the same with my programme. If you enter len=1 and vet[]={0x01} the output is 01=1 and 10=0 but the true output should be 0 and 0. Why this problem?

Comment: @marcoteto ?? input is 0x01 => 0000 0001  -> one transition from 0 to 1. Output looks correct to me. For output 0/0 enter `vet[] = {0};` or `vet[] = { 0xFF };` (for `len = 1;` of course)

Comment: @marcoteto oh wait.. my code takes `len` as number of BYTES, not bits... so, that's the problem. For my code only 8*len bit lengths are possible.

Comment: how can i change bytes into bits? Thanks to the reply

Comment: @marcoteto well... by changing the code to work like that? BTW, as my code is treating bits from top to low, the correct 1 bit input would be `vet[] = {0x80}`, not `0x01`. One option to extend my code for bits is to do ahead of my call padding, i.e. `lenByte = len/8;` `bitsRemaining = len&7;` and then to copy bit `(1<<(7-bitsRemaining))` to the remaining lower bits (0x80 -> 0xFF). Or just make sure the padding bits are 0, then when `(0 != len&7) && last_bit_is_1` you know you have one "wrong" "1->0" transition, which can be subtracted from result.

Comment: @marcoteto but there's probably little real world practical usage for this task done over bit counts... and overall it looks like school exercise. So you should probably do it in more naive way, similar to your first try, as my way is a bit more complex for no obvious reason (better performance when the transitions are very sparse), using somebody's else code without even understand it is pointless, it will do you more damage than help. Take both answers you have and try to understand how they work (debug them, single-step over instructions and watch how CPU state does change), then fix yours.